# Global variables are null when using ViewModel between fragments (Java-Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I am trying to share data between fragments using the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) architecture. I have created the ViewModel class which works fine and sharing data between the fragment and parent class works fine but sharing data between fragments is not working. Below is the receiving fragment and I get a NullPointerException on the `binding.testTextView.setText(s);` line.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;
    private MainActivityViewModel mainActivityViewModel;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        mainActivityViewModel.getVideos().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                binding.testTextView.setText(s);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Using a debugger and breakpoint, it is evident that on that line, any global variable belonging to this fragment is null. I suspect this is because of the `requireActivity()` and that it's not actually referring to this fragment and instead it should be something else. In place of `requireActivity()` I have tried other things such as:

- `getViewLifecycleOwner()`
- `getActivity()`
- `getView()`

but none of these seem to be working. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciate.

For reference I have added the following relevant code from the sending fragment and ViewModel class.

Sending Fragment:

```
        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mainActivityViewModel.setVideos(binding.enterUrl.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> url = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setVideos(String url) {
        this.url.setValue(url);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getVideos() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

P.S. I am aware the variable names are not the best and will be changing them accordingly.

Comment: Can you post the all code of your fragment where the NullPointerException is occured. It looks like you might have just forgot to assign the global `binding` variable in earlier lifecycle.

Comment: @Ashok sure, will edit the post now

Comment: @Ashok I should also point out that it's not just the ```binding``` variable that is showing as null, I have created other variables just for the purposes of testing and they are all null once inside that lambda expression.

Comment: Your problem is your `observe(getActivity())`, not necessarily anything to do with your ViewModel. That `observe` is causing your fragment to receive callbacks even after its view is destroyed and even after the whole fragment is destroyed.

Comment: ah i see, that makes sense, thanks